# In woocommerce subscription while switching subscription how to keep active previous old subscription keep active

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, woocommerce-subscriptions

In woocommerce subscription while switching subscription how to keep active previous old subscription keep active for maximum 3 susbcription orders and in my plugin i had customize like if user downgrade susbcription then the subscription will go "on-hold" status for 1 month , after 1 month the status changed to "processing" and "active" and if user upgrade the subscription the status will go on processing and active , the problem is when subscription switch to upgrade or downgrade the previous susbcription status turns to cancel problem , i want previous subscription to active, Thanks in advance .

Regards

I'd tried this code for upgrading and downgrading susbcirption.

```
add_action('woocommerce_order_status_completed', 'updating_order_status_with_subscription_changes');

function updating_order_status_with_subscription_changes($order_id) {
    $order = wc_get_order($order_id);

    if (wcs_order_contains_subscription($order)) {
        $subscriptions = wcs_get_subscriptions_for_order($order_id);
        foreach ($subscriptions as $subscription_id => $subscription) {
            $subscription_change = check_subscription_change($subscription);

            if ($subscription_change == 'downgrade') {
                // Set the subscription to 'on-hold' if it's a downgrade
                $subscription->update_status('on-hold');

                // Set the order status to 'on-hold' as well
                $order->update_status('on-hold', 'Subscription downgraded, setting order to on-hold.');

                // Schedule event to reactivate subscription
                $date_one_minute_later = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime('+1 minutes'));
                wp_schedule_single_event(strtotime($date_one_minute_later), 'reactivate_subscription', array('subscription_id' => $subscription_id));

                // Schedule event to update order status to 'processing'
                wp_schedule_single_event(strtotime($date_one_minute_later), 'update_order_status_to_processing', array('order_id' => $order_id));
            } elseif ($subscription_change == 'upgrade') {
                // Keep or set the subscription to 'active' if it's an upgrade
                $subscription->update_status('active');
            }
            // No specific action for no change
        }
    }
}

function check_subscription_change($subscription) {
    // Logic to determine if the subscription is a downgrade or an upgrade
    $user_id = $subscription->get_user_id();
    $current_total = $subscription->get_total();

    // Get all subscriptions for the user
    $user_subscriptions = wcs_get_users_subscriptions($user_id);

    foreach ($user_subscriptions as $user_subscription) {
        if ($user_subscription->get_id() != $subscription->get_id()) {
            if ($user_subscription->get_total() < $current_total) {
                return 'downgrade'; // Found a previous subscription that was more expensive
            } elseif ($user_subscription->get_total() > $current_total) {
                return 'upgrade'; // Found a previous subscription that was less expensive
            }
        }
    }

    return 'no_change'; // No significant change found
}

// Handler to reactivate the subscription
add_action('reactivate_subscription', 'reactivate_subscription_handler');

function reactivate_subscription_handler($subscription_id) {
    $subscription = wcs_get_subscription($subscription_id);
    if ($subscription && $subscription->has_status('on-hold')) {
        $subscription->update_status('active');
    }
}

// Handler to update order status to 'processing'
add_action('update_order_status_to_processing', 'update_order_status_to_processing_handler');

function update_order_status_to_processing_handler($order_id) {
    $order = wc_get_order($order_id);
    if ($order && $order->has_status('on-hold')) {
        $order->update_status('processing', 'Auto-updating order status to processing after subscription downgrade.');
    }
}
```